# Which MacBook Air models use an SSD compatible with my mid-2013 11" A1465?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, compatibility

I got a damaged MacBook Air for free a few years ago with the screen not working and the SSD missing. I got it fixed and working with a USB3 external drive and it's been great for years.

Now I'm shopping for a secondhand internal SSD replacement. I know these machines used proprietary SSDs and they varied a lot from model to model.

Most people that sell these privately just list what model the part is from. So I need to know which other models used the same part as mine.

The specs of my MacBook:

- Mid-2013
- 11" non-Retina
- Core i5
- model A1465

I've found some sites that let me identify my machine and tell me which original or which 3rd party SSDs will fit. But I can't seem to find which other MacBook Air models used the same SSDs.

Armed with this knowledge I'll be able to hunt in my local equivalent of Craigslist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web article gives everything you every wanted to know about Apple SSDs.
https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

Your model came with an Apple "Generation 3" SSD, used in Mid-2013 to Late 2014 models*, with a 12+16 pin connector; but it can take the faster 'Generation 4' modules found in 2015 Macs. Gen 4 modules are identifiable by the code SSUBX.

*( * The Mid-2015 iMac is a Gen 3 outlier.)*

Note that there are now third-party modules, made by companies like OWC, which claim to be faster than the OEM parts.

Comment: Yes the OWC ones seem very expensive here in Australia whereas used OEM ones vary a lot and thanks to your answer I might be able to find a cheap one. Thanks very much!

Comment: @hippietrail You can even find unused ones. I got a 1TB module for my 2014 MBP, which had 0 bytes used. You may want to check if the 1TB units fit the AIR, as they're wider than the others.